# Does tropicalization commute with composition?

Tags: polynomials, tropical-geometry, tropical-arithmetic

Say we have two polynomials
$$
f = \sum d_n x^n, \quad g = \sum_n b_n x^n
$$
that tropicalize to
$$
F = \max(d_n + nx), \quad G = \max(b_n + nx).
$$
Can we say $f\circ g$ tropicalizes to $F\circ G$?

More generaly, let $f = f_1 / f_2$ and $g = g_1 / g_2$ are rational functions, $f_i, g_i \in (\mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n])^n$, that tropicalize to differences of maximas $F = F_1 - F_2$ and $G = G_1 - G_2$, respectively.
Can we say $f\circ g$ tropicalizes to $F\circ G$?

**Note:** As pointed out in a comment, this is not true at least if $f$ and $g$ are allowed to have free terms. For instance, $f= x^2$, $g=x+1$ gives $\text{Trop}(f\circ g) = \max(2x, 2+x, 1)$ and $F\circ G = 2\max(x, 1)$. These do not coincide in the whole line.

---

My intuition is that the first question should be answered "yes", by just expressing
$$
f\circ g = \sum_n d_n \left(\sum_m b_m x^m\right)^n
$$
and
$$
F\circ G = \max_n \left(d_n + n\cdot\max_m(b_m + m\cdot x)\right),
$$
and arguing that the distribution laws in both semirrings behave similarly.

The second statement is, at least, backed up by some experimental data. I also believe it should be a "yes" by a similar reasoning. But I am not an expert on tropical geometry and may have wrong intuition.

Comment: My first intuition would be no. Expanding the expression for $f\circ g$ gives a lot of binomial coefficients that dont show up in the tropicalized version. What happens for example for $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x+1$?